# Leaflet js style geojson layer according to zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, style, zoom

Leaflet js beginner following/adapting the choropleth [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). I need to get something like this [mapbox map](https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00250/) where the feature styles change according to zoom level. I am loading a line geojson that gets style from getColor / getWidth functions related to feature.properties. How do I get the weight to be 1 when currentZoom is <= 16?

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(roads, {
      style: style
    }).addTo(map);

function getColor(p) {
  return p >= 100 ? '#00F7BD' :
    p >= 40 ? '#24abc9' :
    p >= 20 ? '#ef561a' : 
    p >= 0 ? '#4D2A2D' : 
    '#feffbd';
}

function getWidth(w) {
   return w > 20 ? 4.8 :
          w > 17 ? 4.5 :
          w > 16 ? 4 :
          w > 15 ? 3.5 :
          w > 14 ? 2.5 :
          w > 10 ? 1.5 :
          w > 0 ? 0.5 :
          0;
}

// map.on('zoomend', function () {
  var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

function style(feature) {
      if (currentZoom <= 16) {
        return {
          color: getColor(feature.properties.paP),
          weight: 1, 
          opacity: 0.5,
        };
      }
      else {
        return {
          weight: getWidth(feature.properties.stW),
          color: getColor(feature.properties.paP),
        };
      }
}
// });
```

Second approach inspired by Stephen's answer @Stephen Lead

```
   function style(feature) {
      var fa;
      return {
          color: getColor(feature.properties.paP),
          weight: fa * getWidth(feature.properties.stW),
          opacity: 0.6,
          lineCap: 'square',
          lineJoin: 'square',
        };
    }

    map.on('zoomend', function () {
        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
            if (currentZoom <= 16) {
                  fa = 0.5;
            }
            else {
                  fa = 3;
            }
    });
```

Comment: If you call the function style () with a feature in argument  it should work. Do you get any js error when you try this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm too beginner to get it. Can you develop further? Look, I'm tweaking my attempts here http://plnkr.co/edit/HClAOxy0jnYdneOVjG5s?p=preview

Comment: When you declare the style properties of geojson features call your function named "style()" like that       `style: style(feature)`

Comment: No, your suggestion doesn't work. Actually, for your reference in the code, the 'else' statement does works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to set the style's `width` property based on the current map scale, and update this whenever the scale changes.

See the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/3nLh6km1/) for an example, and zoom in to see the width increase:

[image]

```
function addStates() {
    // this function adds the states layer with the style's weight determined
    // by the current zoom level
    geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: style
    }).addTo(map);
  }

function style(feature) {
    // the weight is a function of the current map scale
    var wt;
    if (map.getZoom() <= 6) {
        wt = 1;
    } else {
        wt = 20;
    }
    return {
        weight: wt,
        ....
    };
}  

// whenever the zoom level changes, remove the layer and re-add it to 
// force the style to update based on the current map scale
map.on("zoomend", function(){
  geojson.removeFrom(map);
  addStates();
});
```

This suggested approach removes the layer each time the scale changes, then adds it again to force the `setStyle` function to recalculate based on the current map scale. It may be possible to make this more efficient, but it seems to work reasonably well.

(I picked zoom level 6 and a width of 20 for an easy demonstration of the effects - it's difficult to determine the difference between a width of 1 and 2 visually)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I can not make it work with the line geojson I am working with. However, your answer made think of a possible ('beginner') solution (see the second approach I added below the original question) Sadly, it still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: you need to set `fa` as a global variable - your current code over-writes whatever value of `fa` exists when the `style` function runs

Comment: Also, you need something to trigger the `style` function and feed it a `feature` - that's why my demo removes the layer and re-adds it, to force the `style` function to be re-run. Simply changing the `fa` value isn't enough to cause the change

Comment: A simple update to my sample is to replace line 33 with something like: `weight: wt * (feature.properties.density / 10),` - this demonstrates how to use a factor based on the map scale * an attribute from the dataset (I've used density since that's available on the sample States json file, and divided by 10 so it displays OK)