# Leaflet setting zoom level for a specified GeoJSON layer feature

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, zoom

I would like to set the level of visibility at the specified GeoJSON feature property.

As a continuation of this query:
[Leaflet distinguishing sublayers within one GeoJSON layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341425/leaflet-distinguishing-sublayers-within-one-geojson-layer?noredirect=1#comment557613_341425)

Where I figured out how to set the radius for an individual GeoJSON feature.properties. Now I would like to set the zoom level for them.

For this purpose I read the stuff here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607766/leaflet-zoom-map-layer

Which is the closest to my problem. Regarding to the advice above I used the following code:

```
 var sitis = L.geoJSON(sitec, {
  style: function(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.Value === "2") {
    return {
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        radius: 8,
        opacity:function(){
            if (zoom > 11) {opacity:0}
            else (zoom < 13) {opacity:1}
            },
        };
    }
    if (feature.properties.Value === "1") {
    return {
        radius: 4
        };
    }
},
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + feature.properties.Head
label = String(feature.properties.Title)
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); //https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245621/how-to-label-geojson-points-in-leaflet
},
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h1><u><font color='red'>"+feature.properties.Title+"</h1></u></font><h2>Address: "+feature.properties.Head+"</h2><p>"+feature.properties.Description+"</p><p> Website:"+feature.properties.URL+"</p><br><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.Pict + " ' style='width:200px;height:300x;'>");
        layer.on({
            mouseover: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#b45501',
                });
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#ff7800',
                });
            }

        });
 }
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

But in the result I got blank page with console saying, that unexpected token has been noticed.

Another attempt was like this:

```
var sitis = L.geoJSON(sitec, {
style: function(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.Value === "2") {
    return {
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        radius: 8
        };
    }
    if (feature.properties.Value === "1") {
    return {
        radius: 4
        };
    }
},
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + 
feature.properties.Head
label = String(feature.properties.Title)
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindTooltip(label, 
 {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); //https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245621/how-to-label-geojson-points-in-leaflet
},
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h1><u><font color='red'>"+feature.properties.Title+"</h1></u></font><h2>Address: "+feature.properties.Head+"</h2><p>"+feature.properties.Description+"</p><p> Website:"+feature.properties.URL+"</p><br><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.Pict + " ' style='width:200px;height:300x;'>");
        layer.on({
            mouseover: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#b45501',
                });
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#ff7800',
                });
            }

        });
 }
    })
    .addTo(map);
    if(map.getZoom()<11{
    geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if(layer.feature.properties.value == "1"){
   layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0});
  }
});
   }
```

However here is the same situation.

**My pure js code is based here:**
https://jsfiddle.net/Krukarius/tq5yfkc6/

My last trial was related to this query:

[Leflet js style geojson layer according to zoom level](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256831/leflet-js-style-geojson-layer-according-to-zoom-level)

Where I created: `function getWidth(w) {` and next wrote code as follows:

```
function getWidth(w) {
return w > 2 ? 8 :
       w > 1 ? 6 :
       w > 0 ? 3 :
       0;
    }

  var currentZoom = map.getZoom();



  var sitis = L.geoJSON(sitec, {
style: function(feature) {
if (currentZoom <=14 {
    return: {
    weight: getWidth(feature.properties.Value),
    };
},
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + feature.properties.Head
label = String(feature.properties.Title)
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); //https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245621/how-to-label-geojson-points-in-leaflet
},
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h1><u><font color='red'>"+feature.properties.Title+"</h1></u></font><h2>Address: "+feature.properties.Head+"</h2><p>"+feature.properties.Description+"</p><p> Website:"+feature.properties.URL+"</p><br><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.Pict + " ' style='width:200px;height:300x;'>");
        layer.on({
            mouseover: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#b45501',
                });
            },
            mouseout: function () {
                this.setStyle({
                    'fillColor': '#ff7800',
                });
            }

        });
  }
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

I try to set the specified zoom level for one of the properties.feature as per the radius value in my previous query from yesterday.

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

[image]

**EDITED:**

Returning to the 2nd attempt:

```
          var sitis = L.geoJSON(sitec).addTo(map);
    //... internal part of the code as above
    if(map.getZoom()<14){
         sitis.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if(layer.feature.properties.Value == "1"){
   layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0, opacity: 0});
  }
  });
 }
 else 
  { 
 layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0.8, opacity: 1});
 }
```

I found, that it partially works. However it still doesn't solve the problem, because layer remains invisible at all zoom levels.

[image]